# REST WADL: Any style guidelines or good examples?

Tags: api, rest, wadl

There are plenty of excellent examples and guidelines (see ref [1]) for writing good javadoc for Java code

We are documenting our REST interfaces via WADL using Restlet

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/72-restlet.html

Quoting that tutorial we are adding code like ...

```
 @Override
    protected void describeDelete(MethodInfo info) {
        info.setDocumentation("Delete the current item.");

        RepresentationInfo repInfo = new RepresentationInfo();
        repInfo.setDocumentation("No representation is returned.");
        repInfo.getStatuses().add(Status.SUCCESS_NO_CONTENT);
        info.getResponse().getRepresentations().add(repInfo);
    }
```

Are there coding standards or examples of good succinct WADL . e,g, we dont want to duplicate info that is implicit in the HTTP verb or the URL.

Ref 1. How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool.
I cant add the URL as I am new user but I mean the guidelines at
    www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part of a RESTful system that needs any additional documentation is custom media types and custom link relations.

Think of it this way, what documentation did you provide to the web browser vendors so that users could access your corporate web site?